# python grouping () and adding text for the word

Tags: python

I have a code which: Groups the same words before `()` and combines and removes redundant data within `()` .It also takes the 'text' from one '()' till the next `()` and groups /add under the same name:

Eg:`Input text file

```
 the cars and computers... 
 Car(ferrari,lamborghini,porsche)
  some manufacturers specialise in "super" cars.
Most people like them.

 Computer(hp,dell,apple,sony,fujitsu)
  These are some laptop manufacturers
car(skoda,audi)
     GOOD cars
```

Expected output by preserving indentation as:

```
the cars and computers...
 Car(ferrari,lamborghini,porsche,skoda,audi)
  some manufacturers specialise in "super" cars.
Most people like them.
    GOOD cars

 Computer(hp,dell,apple,sony,fujitsu)
  These are some laptop manufacturers
```

I have completed a code which combines the () and removes redundant data,but its not grouping the lines and adding to the same word before() and not removing the added up text.

My code:

```
import re
import collections
class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []
with open('texta.txt', "r+") as f:
    # so specific lines can be edited
    lines = f.readlines()
    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')
    current_group = None
    for line in range(len(lines)):
        curr_line = lines[line]
        # to prevent searches on lines with no group
        if "(" in curr_line:
            curr_line = curr_line.strip()
            m = group_pattern.match(curr_line)
            if m:
                group_name, group_members = m.groups()
                groups[group_name].members += filter(lambda x: x not in groups[group_name].members, group_members.split(','))
                current_group = group_name          
            else:
                if (current_group is not None) and (len(line) > 0):
                     groups[current_group].text.append(line)

    already_seen = []
    for line in range(len(lines)):
        curr_line = lines[line]

        for key in groups.keys():
            if key in curr_line.strip():
                if key in already_seen:
                    lines[line] = ""
                else:
                    already_seen.append(key)
                    open_par = curr_line.index("(")
                    close_par = curr_line.index(")")
                    member_str = ",".join(groups[key].members)    
                    lines[line] = curr_line[:open_par+1] + member_str + curr_line[close_par:]
    f.truncate()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
```

Please help me to fix my code!Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please post your actual output?

Comment: thats the output i get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's wrong with your code. It seems like you are never actually adding text to the groups...

Anyhow, you can simplify the data-aggregation part to this:

```
import re
import collections
with open('texta.txt', "r+") as f:
    p = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$')
    group_ids = collections.OrderedDict()   # group -> set of ids (?)
    group_words = collections.OrderedDict() # group -> list of words
    group = None                            # last group, or None
    for line in f:
        match = p.match(line)
        if match:
            group, ids = match.groups()
            group_ids.setdefault(group, set()).update(ids.split(','))
        elif line.strip() and group:
            group_words.setdefault(group, []).append(line.rstrip())
```

After this, `group_ids` and `group_words` will be

```
{'car': set(['ab', 'ef', 'ad', 'cd']), 'bike': set(['ac', 'de'])}
{'car': ['go', 'drive', 'enjoy'], 'bike': ['ride']}
```

Writing those to the file in the desired format should not be much of a problem, e.g.:

```
with open('textb.txt', 'w') as f:
    for group, ids in group_ids.items():
        f.write("%s(%s)\n" % (group, ','.join(ids)))
        for word in group_words[group]:
            f.write(word + '\n')
        f.write('\n')
```

This will produce this output: (`bla` was another block after the second `car` block, for testing)

```
car(ab,ef,ad,cd)
 go
 drive
 enjoy

bike(ac,de)
    ride

bla(xx)
 blub
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to use `r+` mode, make sure to do `f.seek(0)` *first* and *then* `f.truncate()`, otherwise the old data will not be erased entirely.

Comment: infact writing to the file finds to be more risky for me.its not preserving indentation and it should write such that already existing text should not be affected!Could u help me in that?

Comment: @Chaeltrims In your example, should the text below the second 'car' block be in the same line, i.e. should there be many empty lines where that second block was, or just one empty line as a separator?

Comment: i needed just an empty line as a seperator!by the way, providing empty lines is more comfortable for you then help me with that!

Comment: Thnx, you worked a lot for my problem,infact i am very weak in writing to the existing file,i did and it produces me lots of indentation problem.So,could you please provide the output in an existing file rather than stdout?

Comment: What kind of indentation problems? Is it all on one line? You have to explicitly add line end characters. Update: Edited again.

Comment: yes,providing output on same line!and I dont know what it means by explicitly add line,i heard this lot of times, but i cant write into file!

Comment: `   group_words.setdefault(group, []).append(line.rstrip())
NameError: name 'group' is not defined
>>>`  it get this error,please help!

Comment: i have copied your code only,then it errors me 'group' not defined!Please help!

Comment: @Chaeltrims Then your input file must have a non-header file before the first header file. You could add `group = None` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: now it shows 'nonetype' obj has no attribute groups()

Comment: @Chaeltrims Edited again. However, if you get these errors, it looks like you have mal-formed input, e.g. non-header lines before the first header line, or header lines not conforming to your regex. With the fix it will work, but those non-conformant lines might get lost in the output. For more help, you'll have to post a more extensive, representative example input.

Comment: its not writing anything to the new file!

Comment: @Chaeltrims Works fine for me, using the input you provide in your question. If you want more help, you'll have to provide more information, e.g. your exact input, or at least a more representative example thereof.